# How can I improve insert performance in ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb

My environment is local machine:
ubuntu 12.04
ArangoDB 2.2.4 or 2.2.3
perl driver(ArangoDB)
CPU: 3 core 6 threads
mem: 3GB

I used save method. Save method is equal to HTTP_GET and HTTP_POST. 
Execute result is following:

1. one perl process, insert 30000 documents. Avg 700 requests/s. 350 HTTP_GET and 350 HTTP_POST.
2. 10 perl process, insert 30000 documents. Avg 1000 requests/s. 500 HTTP_GET and 500 HTTP_POST.

After running 30 seconds, It'll report HTTP 500 error. I modified perl driver(ArangeDB) code for retrying it. So I can finish this test.

arangodb's log is following when it reported HTTP 500 error.

```
2014-10-04T14:46:47Z [26642] DEBUG [./lib/GeneralServer/GeneralServerDispatcher.h:403]   shutdownHandler called, but no handler is known for task
2014-10-04T14:46:47Z [26642] DEBUG [./lib/GeneralServer/GeneralServerDispatcher.h:403] shutdownHandler called, but no handler is known for task
```

I hoped my program can execute avg 3000-5000 requests/s and reduce HTTP 500 error. What's improvements I can use. Thanks!

UPDATE BY 7/10/2014, My insert sample script is following. And I replaced save method by AQL. 
One perl process, insert 10000 documents, Avg 900 requests/s, 1000 HTTP_POST/s. (no HTTP 500)
One perl process, insert 30000 documents, Avg 700 requests/s, 700 HTTP_POST/s. (There will issued HTTP 500, need retry it)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use ArangoDB;

my $itdb = ArangoDB->new(
{
    host       => '10.211.55.2',
    port       => 8529,
    keep_alive => 1,
}
);

# Find or create collection
$itdb->create('Node_temp',{isVolatile => JSON::true});
ImpNodes();

sub ImpNodes{

    for(1..30000){
        my $sth = $itdb->query('INSERT {
            "id": "Jony",
            "value": "File",
            "popup": "public",
            "version": "101",
            "machine": "10.20.18.193",
            "text": {
               "Address": ["center","bold","250","100"]
            },
            "menuitem":[
            {
                "value": "New",
                "onclick": "CreateNewDoc",
                "action": "CreateNewDoc"
            }
            ,
            {
                "value": "Open",
                "onclick": "OpenNewDoc",
                "action": "OpenNewDoc"
            },
            {
                "value": "Close",
                "onclick": "CloseDoc",
                "action": "CloseDoc"
            },
            {
                "value": "Save",
                "onclick": "SaveDoc",
                "action": "SaveDoc"
            }]
        } in Node_temp');

        my $cursor = $sth->execute({
            do_count => 1,
            batch_size => 10,
        });
    }
}
```

And I have modified Arangodb-0.08 for inserting smoothly in Connection.pm. 
http_post method:

```
$retries = 100 #for testing
for(1..$retries){
    ( undef, $code, $msg, undef, $body ) = $self->{_http_agent}->request(
        %{ $self->{_req_args} },
        method     => 'POST',
        path_query => $path,
        headers    => $headers,
        content    => $data,
    );
    last if ( $code < 500 || $code >= 600 );
    print "The return code is 5xx,retry http_post!\n";
    print $code, " : " , $msg , " : " , $body;
    select(undef, undef, undef, 3);
}
```

Comment: Is there any message returned with the HTTP 500 error? Additionally, is it possible to supply your perl test program with the modified driver for reproduction?

Comment: Is it actually necessary to do a GET and a POST operation? Saving a document only requires one HTTP POST, so I guess you're issueing the GET to ensure that the document is not yet there, right? If your goal is only saving the document, the HTTP GETs can be omitted altogether.

Comment: The returned message is  "500 : Internal Response: Cannot connect to 10.211.55.2:8529: Cannot assign requested address at /home/netdisco/.plenv/versions/5.19.8/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.19.8/ArangoDB/Connection.pm line 73.". The message is from http_post in Connection.pm.

Comment: I use "ArangoDB-0.08" from perl CPAN. In "save" method, "$self->{connection}->http_post( $api, $data )" will send http_post, and "ArangoDB::Document->new( $self->{connection}, $res )->fetch" will send http_get. I think it's doesn't matter. I can modify it, and delete http_get.

Comment: I have attached my test program in question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for posting the code here! As far as I can see, the test client opens 30,000 connections to ArangoDB, featuring calls to system calls socket(), ioctl(), connect() etc. This is probably one of the reasons you're not getting much throughput. I don't see the ArangoDB server responding with an HTTP 500 at all when I run the script. The problem to me seems that the client script runs out of sockets and raises the 500 error itself when the OS runs out of free ports to assign.

Comment: Thanks for your details! If you use perl ArangoDB, you need add "print $code, " : " , $msg , " : " , $body;" in http_post method in Connection.pm. And you'll maybe see HTTP 500. Of course, if your server is more powerful, you need open more than 30000 connections. I use arangob for testing performance in the same server, arangob is much more faster than my perl client. I hope we can get that performance with perl or python client. BTW, I move insert.pl and ArangoDB to MAC OSX 10.9.5(cpu: i7 4core 8threads). The result is similar to ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strace'd the client program and could verify that a new connection is opened for each request. This causes many system calls to be issued. strace looks like this for **each** request:

```
17300 socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
17300 ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, 0x7fffaee760c0) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
17300 lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)             = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
17300 ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, 0x7fffaee760c0) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
17300 lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)             = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
17300 fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)     = 0
17300 setsockopt(3, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
17300 fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                 = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
17300 fcntl(3, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
17300 connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8529), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
17300 select(8, NULL, [3], [3], {299, 999526}) = 1 (out [3], left {299, 999524})
17300 write(3, "POST /_api/cursor HTTP/1.1\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nUser-Agent: Furl::HTTP/3.05\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 1032\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1:8529\r\n\r\n", 176) = 176
17300 write(3, "{\"count\":true,\"query\":\"INSERT {\\n            \\\"id\\\": \\\"Jony\\\",\\n            \\\"value\\\": \\\"File\\\",\\n            \\\"popup\\\": \\\"public\\\",\\n            \\\"version\\\": \\\"101\\\",\\n            \\\"machine\\\": \\\"10.20.18.193\\\",\\n            \\\"text\\\": {\\n               \\"..., 1032) = 1032
17300 read(3, 0x15f0af0, 10240)         = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
--
17300 close(3)                          = 0
17300 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [PIPE], [], 8) = 0
17300 rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7faa49b221f0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7faa49b221f0}, 8) = 0
17300 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
17300 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [PIPE], [], 8) = 0
17300 rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7faa49b221f0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7faa49b221f0}, 8) = 0
17300 rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
```

I think you will want to avoid establishing and closing connections on each request. This also solves the problem with the OS running out of ports.

To keep the driver from re-opening connections all the time I had to modify FURL as follows:

In line 526 of Furl/HTTP.pm, FURL checks the HTTP response headers it gets from the server. It will read the `Connection` from the response header there, and compare the header value with the string `keep-alive`. The problem is that this does not take into account a different case of the response header. ArangoDB returns a header value of `Keep-Alive` (mind the caps), so FURL does not recognize it properly.

The following change to Furl/HTTP.pm fixes that:

```
-    if ($connection_header eq 'keep-alive') {
+    if (lc($connection_header) eq 'keep-alive') {
```

This makes the clients not close the connection after each request and not run out of ports.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 'keep-alive' is no effect, a lot of insert will cause HTTP 500. After I modified Furl/HTTP.pm according to your method, HTTP 500 error is disappeared. I used strace again. "connect" is only one each request.

Comment: After I modified Furl/HTTP.pm. I executed insert.pl again. HTTP 500 is disappear, but performance doesn't be improved remarkablely. Insert 100,000 documents, it consumes 110 second. Avg 900 requests/s.

Comment: I use Parallel::ForkManager for open 5 insert processes. Insert 100,000 documents, it consumes 64s. Avg 1560 requests/s. It's double performance. If I open 10 insert processes, Insert 100,000 documents, it consumes 70s. So I think multi-process can't give me 3000-5000 reqs/s. And I use Furl/HTTP.pm for doing nothing, Furl/HTTP.pm can send 2900 HTTP request/s in one process.

Comment: I am not sure about how the Parallel::ForkManager works internally. Can you make sure that when you use 5 insert processes it actually uses 5 connections to ArangoDB? Or does it share the one connection between all 5 processes (which I doubt would work, but just to make sure).

Comment: Another thing that you may try is to not use an AQL query to insert a single document but to use the HTTP POST method on /_api/document to insert a document. The docs for this are here: http://docs.arangodb.org/HttpDocument/WorkingWithDocuments.html Working with single documents should have a slightly lower overhead per call than when issuing AQL queries

Comment: One more possibility: collect documents to insert on the client side and send them in batches using the batch API: http://docs.arangodb.org/HttpBatchRequest/README.html

Comment: I removed Parallel::ForkManager, and execute the same script by manual. The performance is the same in ubuntu VM(2cpu). But I execute the script in my Mac(i7 4core8Threads), the performance can reach avg 3300 reqs/s. I watched cpu load is very high.(400% cpu means it consumes 2core4threads)

Comment: Coming back to my suggestion of using HTTP POSTs to `/_api/document` instead of executing AQL queries for single document inserts: using a single-threaded client, I am getting much higher throughput for single document inserts than for AQL queries. This is expected, as AQL queries are more general and produce more overhead than just-inserts. Have you tried this out?

Comment: I modified insert.pl to HTTP POST only today. Using a single-threaded client, it reached avg. 2000 requests/s in ubuntu(2cpu). Using 5 clients, it reached avg. 4200 requests/s in ubuntu(2cpu). It's higher throughput than AQL. Do you have a better result?

Comment: My results will be different because I use a different server. You may also get an increase by buffering some inserts in your client program and sending them in batches once you have collected a few. A speedup may also be achieved by using fire & forget requests using the `X-Arango-Async: true` header with each insert. More on this can be found here: https://www.arangodb.org/2013/11/22/measuring-arangodb-insert-performance

Comment: I tried to use "X-Arango-Async: true". A single-threaded client can reach avg. 3850reqs/s. 3 clients can reach 5300 reqs/s. The result is pretty good. But I have another two questions. One question is the flag is "X-Arango-Async: true" or "X-Arango-Async: store". Somewhere is "store" in manual, another is "true". The second is how long can I ensure the data have been inserted to database if I set "X-Arango-Async: true", and I can use them.

Comment: `X-Arango-Async: true` means "fire and forget": there is no way to get the result of the insert operation from the server (apart from looking into the collection to check if the document is there). `X-Arango-Async: store` will tell the server to persist the result of the operation in memory until you fetch it. It will return an ID to you that you can use to fetch the result later (using HTTP GET to `/_api/job`: http://docs.arangodb.org/HttpAsyncResultsManagement/README.html). Results of operations will stay on the server until they are fetched. This may cause leaks if results are not fetched.

Comment: There is no way to predict when an `X-Arango-Async` operation will have finished on the server. The header tells the server to queue the operation and execute it as soon as possible. This may take a while if the queue is long already.